# JSF2.0 Blank Input field in is not setting as NULL

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a backing bean where  filelds are Long , Double , Integer , String 
When I am not specifying anything in input field it is taking as zero for Long, Integer and Double instead of null. I am using tomcat to deploy my app. Is there any solution? I have tried the following context parameter, but it does not work.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following VM argument to Tomcat startup options.

```
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false
```

You also need to ensure that you've declared `faces-config.xml` conform the JSF 2.0 specification.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <!-- Your config here -->
</faces-config>
```

Otherwise JSF 2.0 specific settings/features won't be activated.

Comment: Hi **BAlusC** thanks for reply . We are Using tomcat 7.0.x And As you said  faces-config.xml is pointing to jsf2.0 . and also we added context-param in web.xml but still it is not working

Comment: Try adding `-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false` to Tomcat startup options.

Comment: I have zipped version of Tomcat7 running on windows  tell me where i have to add this  line **Thanks**

Comment: We also got some code LIke 'System.getProperties().put("org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO", "false");'  but this is also not working

Comment: If you run it by `catalina.bat`, then you can edit it there. If you run it by an IDE like Eclipse, you can edit it in server settings.

Comment: I m really sorry to disturb you too much but i am not getting how to add  it and where to add it , I am really confused and not getting anything where i have to add, and how do i start tomcat using catalina.bat ???

Comment: How exactly are you starting and running Tomcat?

Comment: I downloaded Tomcat 7.0.14  I seted up  JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME var in path , then  i am going to bin directory in Catalina_HOME and typing startup.bat

Comment: OK, the `startup.bat` uses `catalina.bat` already. You can edit it there (requires `.bat` knowledge though). I think it's for you easier to just set it as environment variable `JAVA_OPTS`. It will be used by `catalina.bat`.

Comment: @BalusC: I have the same problem, but my server is JBoss AS 7.1. `faces-config.xml` is set as you instructed but the problem continues. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

NB : The above does not work if the element is placed within `<ui:repeat>`, but works if replaced with `<c:forEach>`