# Integer getting default value 0 where it required to be NULL in Java

Tags: jsf, integer

My requirement looks simple, but I feel I'm doing something wrong in code.

All I need is to insert "null" in Oracle Database when nothing is passed from InputText field of UI.

**PaymantSpecFormPage.xhtml**

```
<h:inputText id="startWeek" value="#{flowScope.paymentSpecVO.paymStartWk}" styleClass="inputTypeForm" maxlength="4"/>
```

**PaymentSpecVO.java**

```
public class PaymentSpecVO extends BaseVO<PaymentSpec> {
   private Integer paymStartWk;

   public Integer getPaymStartWk() {
      return paymStartWk;
   }
   public void setPaymStartWk(Integer paymStartWk) {
      this.paymStartWk = paymStartWk;
   }
}
```

And in my DB Table

```
COLUMN_NAME      DATA_TYPE    NULLABLE    DEFAULT_VALUE
------------     ---------    --------    -------------
PAYM_START_WK    NUMBER(4,0)    Yes             null
```

And when I enter nothing in inputText, then instead of null, 0 is getting entered in Table, which has different meaning in my business logic, please help me to do necessary code changes.

Comment: Make a method ! ,, if InputText is null ?  return a default value null

Comment: <h:inputText id="startWeek" value="#{flowScope.paymentSpecVO.paymStartWk}" styleClass="inputTypeForm" maxlength="4"/> has to work like this, but not in case of Integer class, thats where the problem araises

Comment: The answer for your question is probably here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098210/jsf2-0-blank-input-field-in-is-not-setting-as-null

Comment: @Badaro It solved my half of problem, and now its storing null values, but while on retrieve it shows 0 again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> *And when I enter nothing in inputText, then instead of null, 0 is getting entered in table*

This problem is recognizable as Tomcat's EL parser not taking into account that you're using `Integer` instead of `int`. You need to add the following VM argument to Tomcat startup options:

```html
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false
```

#### See also:

- [h:inputText which is bound to Integer property is submitting value 0 instead of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116517/hinputtext-which-is-bound-to-integer-property-is-submitting-value-0-instead-of)
- [Work around for faulty INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL in Mojarra JSF 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304025/work-around-for-faulty-interpret-empty-string-submitted-values-as-null-in-mojarr)

---

> *It solved my half of problem, and now its storing null values, but while on retrieve it shows 0 again*

This problem is recognizable as JDBC under the covers using `ResultSet#getInt()` instead of `ResultSet#getObject()`. This is however essentially a different problem than the first one. You didn't tell anything about how your database access layer is setup, so it's hard to point out a concrete solution.

Comment: I have used -Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false, as an argument and my business logic are making use of Integer datatype rather than int.  I'm using Spring Data JPA to persist entries.  @Transactional(readOnly = false)
 public PaymentSpec save(PaymentSpec PaymentSpec);

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Spring. You'd better ask a separate question why a `NUMBER` field with a `null` value is obtained as `0` from Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Thank you, I love to read your comments :)

Comment: @BalusC this issue actually exists in JBoss Wildfly 8.2.0 final. I have a `MessageBean` with an `Integer` variable that is null but when doing `#{not empty value}` the component gets rendered. Is there a way of treating `null` `Integer` as null in JSF EL?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you are reading that xhtml.
At java layer, you can override either the constructor of PaymentSpecVO or the setter for paymStartWk

Comment: Hi, Tried private Integer paymStartWk = null; but seems no luck!

Comment: PaymentSpecVO() {setPaymStartWk(null);}

Comment: paymStartWk = null; and PaymentSpecVO() {setPaymStartWk(null);} run in vain, stills sets default value as 0.

Comment: Then your setter is called somewhere else. You need to check that part

Comment: <h:inputText id="startWeek" value="#{flowScope.paymentSpecVO.paymStartWk}" styleClass="inputTypeForm" maxlength="4"/>, here the JSF component inputText makes use of both setter and getter.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    public class PaymentSpecVO extends BaseVO<PaymentSpec> {
    private String paymStartWk;

    public String getPaymStartWk() {
    return paymStartWk;
    }
    public void setPaymStartWk(Integer paymStartWk) {
    this.paymStartWk = paymStartWk+"";
  }
}
```

But then you might be needing a lot of parsing there.

Edit*

If you enter nothing to your "input Text" the passed value is null but since you're catching it with an Integer, it interprets null to 0.
So when you save it, even after manipulating methods and variables to null , it will store "0" , because basically thats the default value.

Another solution I think is making a custom class that stores Integers

Example :

```
    public class IntegerVal extends Number {
    private Max_val = 10000000;
    private Min_val = -10000000;
    private String default = null;
    }
```

you can do whatever implementations you want ,, like returning null,

You can use that as a substitute to the Integer Class you are using , if you dont wanna use String

Comment: I make use of Spring Data JPA save() method to store in Table, And it would be nice If logic is implemented using Integer instead of String class.

Comment: If you enter nothing to your "input Text" the passed value is null but since you're catching it with an Integer that interprets null to 0.

Comment: Integer is only a wrapper class but its not an Object, Objects default value is null, the numeric primitive type has a default value of 0

Comment: Agreed, but how do I set Integer to null in my bean if I enter nothing ? And Integer being a class it can store null value where as int being a primitive cannot store null.

Comment: You cant, yes it can store null but you cant get the value back, it will return 0.

Comment: To my bad its stores 0 and returning 0.

Comment: @Inayathulla Check my edits , if it can help

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this is actual problem while Integrating JSF with Tomcat.